# Jenkins ClearCase UCM plugin creates empty views

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I upgraded an old Jenkins I had to latest version (**1.550**) and along with it, I updated my CC plugins to latest (ClearCase UCM baselines: **1.7.4** and Jenkins ClearCase Plug-in **1.4**).
In the old setup I had, all was good. Views were created well with latest UCM streams sources.
Now, with the new setup, the views are created but with empty load rules. No files are added and I'm left with a valid, but empty view...

I added a custom declaration of my load rules (**Define load rules manually**), which helped populate the view, but I wanted the plugin to resolve it automatically.

Anyone have an idea here?

Answer (score 1):

None of this [issues for this plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20=%20%27clearcase%27) mentions a problem with load rules (so you could report it).

I usually check the log to see what exact `cleartool mkview` is done, and I try to do it from the command-line to check if the resulting config spec is correctly generated (and it should, since it is based on an UCM stream).

Comment: The mkview commands before and after the upgrade are identical. The only difference is that in the old version, the update command included the **-add_loadrules** and the new version does not (unless I specify it in the job's configuration).

Comment: @EldadAK What version of the ClearCase plugin did you have before the upgrade? The only "recent" modifications involving add_loadrules are https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/commit/25eb6182b8899457b1f618ed06a21c02246b0b49 (1.3.9) and https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/commit/970c6fe4bec07de25845cde9d87ac2b45a0bbdea (1.3.6)

Comment: ClearCase Plugin: **1.3.7**. ClearCase UCM Baseline Plugin: **1.7.4**

Comment: @EldadAK Ok, so it is possible that downgrading the ClearCase plugin to 1.3.7 could have an effect to the load rules management. (Just to check if this is indeed the issue here)